# Installing unstable MongoDB on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I've been trying to install the unstable version on Ubuntu 10.10 using apt
I've installed it from source before, but decided that the apt option might be a better route to go.

I've followed the instructions given at the [mongodb docs site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages) but when running:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen-unstable
```

I get the following error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package mongodb-10gen-unstable is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> **E: Package 'mongodb-10gen-unstable' has no installation candidate**

But it works fine when running (trying to install the stable version):

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

The mongoDb docs states

> We publish 2 distinct packages, named
>   **mongodb-10gen**, **mongodb-10gen-unstable**
>   corresponding to our latest stable
>   release, our latest development
>   release.

So the package name should fine.

Same thing happend when running:

```
aptitude install mongodb-10gen-unstable
```

> No candidate version found for mongodb-10gen-unstable
>   No candidate version found for mongodb-10gen-unstable
>   No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
>   0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.

Is there another repository or something I should add for the unstable version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peek into:

http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit/dists/dist/10gen/binary-amd64/ or http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/10gen/binary-amd64/

or... I won't link every directory but these packages are not packed currently.

Whether they will be or not, ask on http://jira.mongodb.org .

Comment: Yeah I had a look in there as well, was hoping someone could provide a link to where I can find the unstable version...

Comment: UPDATE: Since question has been open for a long time, I've accepted your as the correct one (since it was the only answer) I've noticed that some times the unstable version appears in the repo...